# Update Mongo variable value with variable itself

Tags: mongodb, variables

I am not at all familiar with javascript and was hoping I could receive some help with a mongo update of a variable.

I have looked at the following question :
[Pass variables into mongo updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614397/pass-variables-into-mongo-updates)

but was confused a bit with the looping and the syntax.

I have a field called "name": "MyName"
I am looking for a way to get the following results using a mongo shell command:
"name": "MyName Is"
with a query as well

How would I do that?
Is this a completely incorrect approach?

```
db.collection.update({"old_id":{$regex:".*_change.*"}}, {$set:{"name":"name" + " Is"}}, {multi:true})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks to be correct, have you tried it? Does it produce the desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: **You cannot!** You cannot update a field using another field. So you cannot update a field using itself. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field).

**BTW:**

This

```
 $set:{"name":"name" + " Is"}
```

will set the `name` property to `"name Is"`.

Comment: thank you so much! I had not seen that question/answer. Guess, I can write a python script to loop through. Thanks

Comment: I sort of figured it would only recognize that as a string, but I was uncertain how to reference the variable name

Comment: You can reference field names in the aggregation_framework (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) using `$`.